# What are "Documents" in Chrome's Performance Monitor?

Tags: google-chrome, dom, browser, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

In a situation where there's no frames used **I see a minimum of 2 documents anywhere I look** even when there's no frames in use.

As I write this question I checked StackOverflow - 12 Documents. What constitutes a document here?

[image]

Comment: They include "isolated world" of every extension that has content scripts running and currently using DOM.

Comment: Helpful! Even with no extensions though, I see a minimum of 2 virtually everywhere. Not sure what to make of that.

Comment: Apparently Chrome (or V8) creates internal documents for whatever reason so this number isn't probably helpful for us normal people. You can inspect a snapshot in devtools -> memory panel.